# Get limit property from action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Model with this properties

```cs
public string app_status_name { get; set; }
public string app_status_value { get; set; }
public string machine_status_name { get; set; }
public string machine_status_value { get; set; }
```

In my IActionResult I want to get limit properties =>like machine_....

How can I limit an inputs ?
I don't want to create another model.

Comment: Can you please share code for action method that shows what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to bind `app_...` with inputs,you can try to use [[Bind] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#complex-types).Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class DataModel
    {
        public string app_status_name { get; set; }

        public string app_status_value { get; set; }
        public string machine_status_name { get; set; }

        public string machine_status_value { get; set; }

    }
```

View:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="TestBind">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            app_status_name
        </label>
        <input name="app_status_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            app_status_value
        </label>
        <input name="app_status_value" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            machine_status_name
        </label>
        <input name="machine_status_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            machine_status_value
        </label>
        <input name="machine_status_value" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

action:

```
public IActionResult TestBind([Bind("machine_status_name,machine_status_value")] DataModel data)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I don't want to show a result to user . Look at my action : 
```
[HttpPost("api/status/machine")]
        public IActionResult statusmachine(Status status)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                status1 = status;
                
                viewModels.status_change(status);
                return Ok("OK");
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```
I just want to set 2 properties of my class to status1( machine_... )
I don't want to get another properties like (app_...) from user request

Comment: What is the structure of  ` status1`,it only has properties `machine_status_name` and  `machine_status_value`?